# Invalid license. Please reactivate Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, licensing

Occasionally I get the following licence error when I try to build my Xamarin project in Visual Studio.

```
Invalid license. Please reactivate Xamarin.Android  P1SyncMono
Unable to determine license edition.    P1SyncMono
```

I am fully licensed with Enterprise for Xamarin.Android (and Xamarin.iOS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio

- Tools -> Xamarin Account...
- Log Out
- Log In
- Restart Visual Studio

https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1641743-manually-refresh-xamarin-licenses (does not mention restarting Visual Studio)